# Gift cards and possible hidden import taxes

Tags: taxes, gift-card, shipping

I live in Canada and want to order something from USA. The total in CAD is $45 (including shipping, but I don't think tax is), and I have a $50 prepaid MasterCard gift card. How do I know if there will be additional import fees or local taxes in my Provence I have to pay? I don't want to lose my money or order because the gift card value is exceeded.
The card is non-refillable and I don't think the total the website is giving me includes tax.
Thanks for any help and please let me know if I need to explain more.

Thank you for this link https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/import/postal-postale/dtytx-drttx-eng.html
This is what I was wondering. 5% extra on the order will still be covered under the gift card, so I will order.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/import/postal-postale/dtytx-drttx-eng.html

Comment: Transaction of gift-card is a payment, it has nothing to do with Import tax. Import tax is paid on the goods imported based on the receipt value which may or may not handle by the merchant.

Comment: Yes that link is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

http://cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/import/postal-postale/dtytx-drttx-eng.html

The CBSA says that there's a 5% duty on imports.

> Any item mailed to Canada may be subject to the Goods and Services Tax (GST) and/or duty. Unless specifically exempted, you must pay the 5% GST on items you import into Canada by mail. The CBSA calculates any duties owing based on the value of the goods in Canadian funds. The duty rates vary according to the type of goods you are importing and the country from which they came or were made in. Depending on the goods or their value, some other taxes may apply, such as excise duty or excise tax on luxury items.

You might also have to pay provincial taxes.